# Button Change Error on Click Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

2 buttons are supposed to be "Add to Favorites" and "Extract from Other Favorites". Here's my code:

```
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" id="FavoriButonex" data-id="<?php echo $sorid ?>">
    <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> Fovorilerimden Çıkar
</button>

<button  type="submit name="favekle" class="like btn btn-success btn-xs" id="FavoriButon" data-id="<?php echo $_GET['soru_id']; ?>" >
     <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> Fovorilerime Ekle
</button>
```

JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/behaviour/general.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#FavoriButon').click(function(){
            var soru_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'soru-detay.php',
                type: 'post',

                data: {
                    'favoriad': 1,
                    'soru_id': soru_id
                },
                success: function(){
                }
            });
        });
        $('#FavoriButonex').click(function(){ 
            var soru_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'soru-detay.php',
                type: 'post',

                data: {
                    'favoriex': 1,
                    'soru_id': soru_id
                },
                success: function(){
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm working on but the button does not change.

When we press the insert button, the eject button should come

button id="FavoriButonex" Click to button id="FavoriButon"

This was translated to English via machine translation (before edits), I apologize for any errors.

Comment: What does your 2 buttons does?

Comment: what do you want to happen when the buttons are clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Change the type for the button to button

`type="button"` you are currently submitting a form(if you have any),
note: you also don't do anything with the ajax response, you need to notify that the ajax was successful or not, alter your success functions

Comment: This button does not come at all when the page is loaded

Comment: what is the use of ajax, why do you need them?

Comment: Posting a page without refreshing and changing the button

Comment: where are you changing the button? your success functions are all empty

Comment: returning if else with db query

Comment: I am very Novice